# Filtering Django Queryset Based on Presence of String

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model which renders a json file in views.py:

```
 def bill_sum(request):
  data = Summary.objects.values('title','summary','summary_text')
  return render(request,'billsummary.html',context={'data':data})
```

Is it possible to filter the summary_text object query by looking up a specific string which I would pass in from urls.py?

Something like using

`from django.db.models import Q` `Summary.objects.values('title;'summary',Q('summary_text'__contains=someword),...)`

Comment: How do you planning to send data via URL? (URL query param or POST payload)?

Comment: I was thinking URL query param as the list of "somewords" is limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure its possible. Try like this:

```
def some_view(request);
    somewords  = request.GET.get('somewords')
    data = Summary.objects.filter(summary_text__icontains=somewords).values('title','summary','summary_text')  # icontains has been used here instead of contains to ignore uppercase/lowercase issues
```